# Opening a new page after drop down selection and sending a parameter with it

Tags: php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down in my page that I am generating via php after getting the rows from a query. This works fine.

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user1', 'qwER$%#RFVD', 'naming_module') 
or die ('Cannot connect to db');

    $result = $conn->query("select surname from Names");

    echo "<div id='dropdown'>";
    echo "<select name='id'>";
    echo '<option value="'.$id.'">Select a name</option>';

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
      unset($id, $name);
      $id = $row['id'];
      $name = $row['name']; 
      echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
    }

    echo "</select>";
    echo "</div>";
?>
```

My target is, once I select a name in the drop down, I want to move automatically to another page and send the text of the selection as a parameter, so that I am able to use it inside another query in there (getting more details about the name from a database)

Can this be done using PHP? (I also have jQuery snippets in my code, so if that is an option, I can also utilize it)

I have tried the below, but it does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
     {
       $("#dropdown").change(function() 
        {
           var name =  $('#dropdown :selected').text(); 
           window.location = 'http://127.0.0.1/my-site/project.php?name='  + name;
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your variable is `projectname` but you're using `name` in your window.location assignment.

Comment: I corrected that. It seems that I found a solution. I posted it below as an answer. Can you please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
You are using wrong parameter here use projectname instead of name in below code.

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() 
  {
   $("#dropdown").change(function() 
    {
       var projectname =  $('#dropdown :selected').text(); 
       window.location = 'http://127.0.0.1/my-site/project.php?name='  +  name;
    });

   });
  </script>
```

Please remember you are using text() function this will provide you text not value for value you need to use val() function.

:) enjoy coding.

Comment: `:selected` make the query engine pick the selected option element so `text()` would return the value in that case. And `projectname` != `name` so maybe edit answer with code that work.

Comment: Can you please provide me live page link,  I will check and correct

Comment: Check with console.log(projectname), what is coming here

Comment: you can also check with alert() and check after changing this is calling or not. If not then check with jquery .on() function

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the id attribute in the select-box for the jquery to work .

```
echo "<div id='dropdown'>";
echo "<select name='id' id='someid'>";
```

Change the id name in your jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
     {
       $("#someid").change(function() 
        {
           var name =  $('#someid:selected').text(); 
           window.location = 'http://127.0.0.1/my-site/project.php?name='  + name;
        });

    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

I was able to get it using

`echo("First name: " . $_GET['name'] . "<br />\n");`